# Google API - OAuth2 - invalid_request

Tags: oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0

I am stuck with this error.
I just successfully received an authorization code and I am trying to exchange it for an access token, but I get the error message "invalid_request".

I am using Apache HttpComponents library (current version) for the request, and there the UrlEncodedFormEntity as I am making a post request.

Here is my request information:

```
Request body: scope=&client_secret=[my_secret]&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain.org%3A8080%2F[some parameters etc...]%3FplatformID%3D3&client_id=23[...]-rg[...].apps.googleusercontent.com&code=[my_encoded_authorizationCode]

Request-URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Request-Method: POST

Request headers -- 

    User-Agent = MAC: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/536.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Safari/536.25     // this is a fake user agent I have set by the header manipulation

    Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Response headers -- 

    Cache-Control = no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

    Pragma = no-cache

    Expires = Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT

    Date = Sun, 02 Dec 2012 11:44:34 GMT

    Content-Type = application/json

    X-Content-Type-Options = nosniff

    X-Frame-Options = SAMEORIGIN

    X-XSS-Protection = 1; mode=block

    Server = GSE

    Transfer-Encoding = chunked

Response:

{

  "error" : "invalid_request"

}
```

Any help?
I am stuck for days, researching and implementing other OAuth2-protocols, but Google's one does not work...

Best greetings and thanks,
Martin Bories